# Slight variation in double computation between runs

Tags: java, unit-testing, double

Another developer has given me an algorithm that returns a series of strings that contain stringified doubles.  I am building unit tests against these string outputs.  About 80% of the time I run my unit tests they all pass.  The other 20% of the time slight variations occur in the double portion of the returned strings.  For example:

```
Expected: ((B,D),(C,A)); : 0.05766153477579324
Found:    ((B,D),(C,A)); : 0.05766153477579325

Expected: (B,(C,(A,D))); : 0.0017518688483315935
Found     (B,(C,(A,D))); : 0.001751868848331593
```

I know that double computations can be imprecise, but I have never heard of them being variant.  I am assured by the algorithm author that the algo is deterministic.  The way that the double is being toStringed is:

```
    for(Tree gt: geneTrees){
        double prob = probList.next();
        total += prob;
        result.append("\n" + gt.toString() + " : " + prob);
    }
```

I am at a bit of a loss explain how this variation is possible.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you log the string inputs to ensure you get the same inputs between runs, *in the same order*?

Comment: To see how much variation a different order can make http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/different-results-summing-double.html I add 1001 values in random order and generate over 1000 different sums. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just based on the summing that you're doing, I suspect that this might be caused by the issue that double addition is not quite commutative or associative -- you'll get different rounding errors if you add doubles in a slightly different order.

Just add a small epsilon for your unit tests, basically.

Comment: This was the problem.  Developer was iterating over a HashMap that determined the order in which doubles were multiplied.  Switched to TreeMap and the computation is reproducible every time.

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` might also work; it's hash-based, but its iteration order is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

```
I am at a bit of a loss explain how this variation is possible.
```

Until there is one cpu architecture/os/programming language to "rule them all" issues like this are going to happen.  You can try and find some way to get the numbers to tie out 100% to the millionth decimal place if you like, but I think this is a waste of time and will likely not last.

```
Any ideas?
```

Pick a precision and only fail a diff if your number fails within that precision.  There is no need to have numbers calculated out to the 10 decimal places if you only care about (or are able to measure) up to the 2nd.

For example, you have this...

```
Expected: ((B,D),(C,A)); : 0.05766153477579324
Found:    ((B,D),(C,A)); : 0.05766153477579325
                                             ^
                                             |
                                             |
                               If this was a 9...would it change the behavior
                               of whoever is using your calculation?
```

In other words...

```
Double expected = 0.05......
Double actual = Double.parseDouble(valueFromFile);

// Instead of doing this....
if(!expected.equals(actual)) {
  // fail test..
}

// Do this (only substitute .0001 with whatever you think an acceptable number is
// based off of the precision possible of the measurement of your input)....
if(Math.Abs(expected - actual) > .0001) {
   // fail test...
}
```

Comment: IEE 754 *is* a standard that "rules them all" when it comes to floating point.